# Sending data from view (javascript) to controller in MVC 5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

So in my index view I receive and display the user's current location in the form of latitude and longitude.

```
(function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        }
    }());
    function showPosition(position) {
        $('#lat').text(position.coords.latitude);
        $('#long').text(position.coords.longitude);

    }
```

Is there a way to send position.coords.latitude and position.coordes.longitude to my index controller? 
Or should I have the user click a button to submit them, like a form ? I am new to using coordinates.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your showPosition function:

```
var postData = { Lat: position.coords.latitude, Long: position.coords.longitude };
$.ajax(
{
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "AjaxTest",
    //dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    success: function (data, status) {
        alert("Pass" + data);
    },
    error: function (ex) {
        alert("Fail" + ex);
    }
});
```

In your controller, you need this action. Give it a better name please:

```
public JsonResult AjaxTest(Position position)
{
    // do whatever you want here. I am simply returning the value.
    return Json("You posted: " +  position.Lat + " items.", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And you will need a model like this:

```
public class Position
{
    public double Lat { get; set; }
    public double Long { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this alert when running the application now: http://i.imgur.com/n12Jy15.png

Comment: Because you need to change the url you are posting to. Did you create that action in the same controller where the view was generated? If not you have to specify the url. I just put the name of the action because the view was generated from the same controller.

Comment: You have a controller named IndexController? Are you sure? And did you created the action I posted in the answer in the IndexController and you are serving the view from the IndexController as well? It is not possible because that has to work. Your url is incorrect. Also if you are doing other work in the action, that may be failing. To start just use my code and once it is working then modify the action method code.

Comment: Sorry, the controller is named HomeController but the inside there is a task for Index, About and Contact. I found some other strange behavior. If I change the postData to position then it works only once. If I want it to work again, I change it back to postData and run and it works but only once, whats going on?

Comment: Ok those are all other issues you are having. Put your view and controller code [here](http://pastebin.com/) and share the link with me. I will take a look.

Comment: it seems that running a new instance of the app in the browser is the problem. If I just refresh the last tab and close the new one, it will retrieve the coordinates just fine.

Comment: Actually , no. It seems its very hit or miss?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129753/discussion-between-codingyoshi-and-crystyxn).

Answer (score 0):

If you can send as a get request then You could format the lat and long into a query string. Then use `window.location` to redirect the browser to whatever route you want. E.g.

```
Window.location.href = querystring
```

Will tack on the query string to the existing route...or if you can extract only a part of the existing route (like the domain only) and tack on the additional segments along with your query string. Checkout `window.location` for all the various options.